# Issue on connection - different results SOAPUI and client created by java

Tags: java, web-services, https, soapui

I have some issue with connection to a webservice. I have a wsdl file that I used to create a new project in *SOAPUI*. I filled all requested field and call the service. All works as expected. 
Then I created the Stub classes with axis2 tools provide to *SOAPUI*. When I tried to use the service I received several errors:

```
1) Related the wrong chain of certificates
2) Transport error: 503 Error: Service Unavailable
```

The first error seems disappear when I add the proxy settings, but the second I'm not able to understand it.
My question is why in *SOAPUI* this webservice works and from java not? Are there some possible cause for this?

Comment: Are you using the correct endpoint url?

Comment: Yes in both cases I used the same endpoint url.